# How would I go about removing a specific character in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have an Arraylist with these attributes as shown below, and some of them have "," and "." and "?" after the words. I would like to replace the character with nothing, so as to remove them. I tried something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        if (words.get(i).contains(",")) {
            newList.add(words.get(i).replace(",", ""));
        } else {
            newList.add(words.get(i));
        }
        words = newList;
    }
```

But to no avail. The ArrayList is called words. Is there a solution I'm not understanding? Thanks! [JAVA]

For context, here is the ArrayList I am working with:

> [=, A, ABILITY, ACCORDED, ACQUIRED, ADULT,, AFTER, AGAIN, AGAINST, AGE, AGE,, ALBERT, ALIENATED, ALL, ALMOST, ALTERED, ALWAYS, AM, AMONG, AN, AND, ANGER, ANY, ANYTHING, APPALLINGLY, APPROACH., ARE, ARE:, ARTS, AS, ASSASSINATION., ASSERTED, AT, ATOM, ATTACHMENT, AUTHORITY, AVERAGE, AWARDED, AWE,, BALANCE, BE, BE., BECAME, BECAUSE, BECOME, BEING, BEING,, BELIEVING, BETTER., BEYOND, BICYCLE., BIG, BIGGER, BOMB,, BORN, BOSOM, BOWL, BRANCHES, BUILT, BUT, BY, CALLED, CAN, CAUSE, CENTRAL, CENTURY, CENTURY,, CHAIR,, CHALLENGES,, CHIEF, CHILDLIKE, CITIZENSHIP, CLEARLY, CLIMB, CLOSED., COLLECTION, COMMON, COMPLEX., CONCERN, COULD, COUNTED, COUNTED., COUNTS, COUNTS,, COURAGE, CRAZY?, CREATIVITY., CURIOSITY, CURIOUS., CURTAIL, DAYS., DEAD;, DEEP, DEMANDS, DEPENDS, DEVELOPED, DEVELOPMENT, DEVOTES, DIAGRAMS, DID, DIFFICULTY, DIRECTION., DO., DOES, DOING, DRASTICALLY, DREAMS, DRIVES, DWELLS, DYING., E, EARLY, EDUCATION, EIGHTEEN., EINSTEIN, EINSTEIN’S, ELECTRIFYING, ELEMENTARY, ELSE, ENCIRCLES, ENCOUNTERED, ENDEAVORS., ENEMY, ENERGY., ENTITY, EQUATION,, EQUATIONS., EVER, EVERYBODY, EVERYONE, EVERYTHING, EXCEEDED, EXCEL, EXISTING., EXPERIENCED, EXTENDED, EYES, FACT,, FACTS,, FACTS., FAMOUS, FAR, FATE, FEEL, FELT, FEW, FIELD, FIGHT, FIGURE, FINISHING, FIRST, FISH, FLOURISHED., FOOL, FOOLS., FOR, FOR., FORGET, FORGIVE., FORGOTTEN, FORM, FOUR, FROM, FRUIT, GARBAGE, GENIUS, GENIUS,, GENIUS., GERMANY,, GIVE, GLOBAL, GOOD, GRAMMAR, GREAT, GREATEST, GROUND-BREAKING, HAD, HAPPY?, HAS, HAVE, HAZY:, HE, HEARTS., HERITAGE, HIM, HIMSELF, HIS, HISTORY, HOW, HUMAN, HUMANITY., I, ICON,, IF, IGNORE., IM, IMAGINATION, IMPORTANT, IN, INDIVIDUAL., INFLUENCED, INFLUENTIAL, INQUISITIVENESS, INSPIRING, INTELLIGENT, INTEREST, INTERVENE., INTO, IS, IS,, ISAAC, IT, ITS, JERSEY, JEW,, JEWISH, JUDGE, JUST, KEEP, KNACK, KNOWLEDGE, KNOWLEDGE., LARGELY, LATER, LEARNED, LEARNING, LEARNING,, LEISURE]

Comment: I use String#replace to replace string matches with "" and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String word : words) {
  newList.add(word.replaceAll("[,.?:;]", ""));
}

words = newList; // if you want to replace the existing `words` list
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rkd0-_D-v)

Comment: That makes so much sense!! Thank you!